# Move element of array to specific position

Tags: java, arrays

How to move element of array to specific position on Android JAVA.
We have

```
int oldPosition, int newPosition
```

and some like

```
JSONObject[] tmp = new JSONObject[999];
```

array of `JSONObjects`

Comment: Use temp variable to store the current value and move the old position value to the temp variable then, move the new position value to the old position finally move the temp value into new position.

Comment: Welcome, please provide the code you have tried to show us that you have take some times on this problem. And of course, you should search for similar question first, this is a simple algorithm problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just move
`tmp[newPosition]=tmp[oldPosition];`

Swap

`JSONObject jo= tmp[oldPosition];`
`tmp[oldPosition]=tmp[newPosition];`
`tmp[newPosition]=jo;`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** There are other ways but you can go through this as well to get your result :)

**Exercise** : You can understand this logic and use `JSONObject` type and do necessary changes, Watch out for `NullPointerExceptions` , handle everything i am lazy to do them

let's say you have int array --> `private  int array[];`

```
 array = new int[]{10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100};
```

call this method if you want to  swap elements,

```
swapNumbers(array,9,1);
```

.

```
 public  int[]  swapNumbers(int [] arr, int possition1, int possition2){
    int temp  = arr[possition2];
    arr[possition2] = arr[possition1];
    arr[possition1] = temp;
    System.out.println("array -->" + Arrays.toString(array));
    return arr;
}
```

out put : array[10, **100**, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, **20**]

---

But that doesn't satisfy you?

you need out put to be like this : array[10, **100**, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

you can use below method

```
resetUpMyArray(array, array[9],1);
System.out.println("array Finally changed-->" + Arrays.toString(array));
```

enjoy,

```
public int[] resetUpMyArray(int[] inputArray, int deleteMeValue,int addMePosition) {
            List resultLinkedList = new LinkedList();

            for (int itemValue : inputArray)
                if (deleteMeValue == itemValue) {
                    System.out.println("Do not add this value"+itemValue);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Do add this value "+itemValue +"position-"+deleteMeValue);
                    resultLinkedList.add(itemValue);
                }

            System.out.println("array -as new L.L->" + resultLinkedList);
            resultLinkedList.add(addMePosition,deleteMeValue);
            System.out.println("array -as new L.L all set->" + resultLinkedList);

            array = new int[resultLinkedList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < resultLinkedList.size(); i++) {
                array[i] = (int) resultLinkedList.get(i); // Watch out for NullPointerExceptions!
            }

            return array;
        }
```

Comment: You should have provide a pseudo code for this, this is more generic (and force OP to do somethind ;) ). But there is easier solution to shift an array from one index to another using the same kind of logic as swapNumbers with a loop too shift the values.

Comment: @AxelH  ;) Yes next time ill keep that in mind.This thing came to my mind and i posted it.Good point from you .Thank you!

Comment: I have writen the algo for the simple solution. It is using the same array instead of a List.

Answer (score 0):

Here is two simple algorithm.

Switch values :

```
switch(array, from, to)
    tmp         = array[to]
    array[to]   = array[from]
    array[from] = tmp
```

That will give something like

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
          |--<---->--|
[10, 20, 60, 40, 50, 30, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

This will simply store the values that will be replace at the index `to` to be place at index `from`

Move and shift values:

This one will move one values a shift the values next.

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
          |------------^
[10, 20,   , 40, 50, 60, 30, 70, 80, 90, 100]
           <-----------
[10, 20, 40, 50, 60, 30, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

For this, the solution is quite the same, store the values in `tmp` but shift every value to fill the gap. This code will only work if `from < to`

```
tmp = array[to]    
i = from
while(i < to)
    array[i] = array[i+1]; --Shift the value
    i = i + 1       
array[to] = tmp;
```